# The existence of adjoint operation on Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, adjoint-operators

I have a question about adjoint operator. I have known that bounded linear operator on Hilbert space has a unique adjoint operator, but I am wondering whether there is similar existence result about bounded linear operator on Banach space? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but it acts on the dual Banach space.

Comment: Sorry, what's the meaning of dual Banach space? Now, I have bonded linear operator from X to Y, and X,Y are Banach space. What possible additional assumptions do I need to prove its adjoinsexistence?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Is there any proof I can find? Thank you.

Comment: Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis (Dover Books on Mathematics) Paperback – February 16, 1999
by A. N. Kolmogorov  (Author), S. V. Fomin  (Author).  And many other similar books.

Comment: You can start looking [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/adjoint_banach.pdf), for example. For short version [here, page 10](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/handouts/banach.pdf) (the same author).

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thank you, I will have a look.

Comment: @A.G. Thanks, I think you mean exercise 1.1, I am trying to prove it.